# Горячие клавиши на команды

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе используется `TabControl`.

На одной из вкладок пользователь может создавать новый проект.

Нужно привязать горячие клавиши <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> для команды создания проекта.

Гугл подсказывает, что горячие клавиши задаются таким образом:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="N" 
                Command="{Binding CreateProjectCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Но загвоздка в том, что когда пользователь находится на вкладке настроек не нужно, чтобы <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> срабатывало.

Можно ли указать свои горячие клавиши для каждой из вкладок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно можно.

```
<TabItem Header="ProjectTab">
    <TabItem.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="N" 
                    Command="{Binding CreateProjectCommand}" />
    </TabItem.InputBindings>   
</TabItem>

<TabItem Header="SettingsTab">
    <TabItem.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="Z" 
                    Command="{Binding OtherCommand}" />
    </TabItem.InputBindings>
</TabItem>
```